# How do a add a value in for with out cloear data in python

Tags: python

I wanna add value in parameter like :

[https://example.com/id='](https://example.com/id=%27) union select (**Here**)

but I don't know how ?

this is my for :

```
number_of_columns = 3
for num in number_of_columns :
            num = "a"
            url = url + "' " + "UNION SELECT " + num
```

I wanna when I change the number_of_columns it add that many I set on that

Comment: Sorry for clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use `input()`

```
>>> number_of_columns = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
Enter the number of columns: 5
```

After this you need to declare the URL variable as an empty string. From your code, I noticed that you haven't done that. If you don't do that and try to create a string inside your loop, then you will get a `NameError: name 'url' is not defined` error. So do the following next-

```
url = 'example_url'
```

Now finally, your for loop has a problem because you are trying to iterate through an `int` variable. This will not work, you will get an error like so - `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. To rectify this, you can use the `range()` function.

So your for loop implementation can be as shown below -

```
>>> for num in range(number_of_columns):
    num = "a"
    url = url+"'"+"UNION SELECT "+num
    print(URL)
```

This will output as

```
example_url'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a'UNION SELECT a
```

If you are wondering why the output looks this way, it is because in every iteration of the loop the `url` variable is getting information from the previous iteration added on to it. If you don't want that to happen, you can consider writing the code as shown below -

```
>>> number_of_columns = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
Enter the number of columns: 5
>>> url = 'example_url'
>>> for num in range(number_of_columns):
    temp = ''
    num = "a"
    temp = url+"'"+"UNION SELECT "+num
    print(temp)

    
example_url'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a
example_url'UNION SELECT a
```